# NameError: name 'freshdatapoly' is not defined - Variable previously defined?

Tags: python, variables, numpy, tuples

I am trying to write a code to divide two polynomials given in binary form (newdata and proofin, respectively). When I run the code, however, I get:

`NameError: name 'freshdatapoly' is not defined`

This confuses me, as I think I did define, and even appended things to it (which seems to give no error). I suspect the same thing may happen afterwards with 'proofpoly' also. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

def transformation_for_numpy_of_o():
    newdata = ("101001")
    freshdata = list(newdata)
    freshdatapoly = []

    for n in freshdata:

        if n == 1:
            freshdatapoly.append(1.0)

        if n == 0:
            freshdatapoly.append(0.0)



def transformation_for_numpy_of_proof():
    proofin = ("101001")
    proofing = list(proofin)
    proofpoly = []

    for n in proofing:

        if n == 1:
            proofpoly.append(1.0)

        if n == 0:
            proofpoly.append(0.0)



def total():

    # Based on http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.polydiv.html

    transformation_for_numpy_of_o()
    transformation_for_numpy_of_proof()
    numer = np.array(freshdatapoly)
    denomin = np.array(proofpoly)
    answer = np.polydiv(numer, denomin)
    print (answer)

total()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`freshdatapoly` is a *local* variable in the `transformation_for_numpy_of_o()` function. It only exists within that function.

Return that value from the function using `return`, then assign it to a new local in `total()`:

```
def transformation_for_numpy_of_o():
    newdata = ("101001")
    freshdata = list(newdata)
    freshdatapoly = []

    for n in freshdata:

        if n == 1:
            freshdatapoly.append(1.0)

        if n == 0:
            freshdatapoly.append(0.0)

    return freshdatapoly
```

and in `total()`:

```
o_transformed = transformation_for_numpy_of_o()
# ...
numer = np.array(o_transformed)
```

You'll need to do this for `proofpoly` used in `transformation_for_numpy_of_proof()` too; that's a local variable in *that* function and not one available to `total()` unless you return it.